# How to get better performace in ProxmoxVE + CEPH cluster

Tags: performance, virtualization, ceph, proxmox

We have been running ProxmoxVE since 5.0 (now in 6.4-15) and we noticed a decay in performance whenever there is some heavy reading/writing.

We have 9 nodes, 7 with CEPH and 56 OSDs (8 on each node). OSDs are hard drives (HDD) WD Gold or better (4~12 Tb). Nodes with 64/128 Gbytes RAM, dual Xeon CPU mainboards (various models).

We already tried simple tests like "ceph tell osd.* bench" getting stable 110 Mb/sec data transfer to each of them with +- 10 Mb/sec spread during normal operations. Apply/Commit Latency is normally below 55 ms with a couple of OSDs reaching 100 ms and one-third below 20 ms.

The front network and back network are both 1 Gbps (separated in VLANs), we are trying to move to 10 Gbps but we found some trouble we are still trying to figure out how to solve (unstable OSDs disconnections).

The Pool is defined as "replicated" with 3 copies (2 needed to keep running). Now the total amount of disk space is 305 Tb (72% used), reweight is in use as some OSDs were getting much more data than others.

Virtual machines run on the same 9 nodes, most are not CPU intensive:

- Avg. VM CPU Usage < 6%
- Avg. Node CPU Usage < 4.5%
- Peak VM CPU Usage 40%
- Peak Node CPU Usage 30%

But I/O Wait is a different story:

- Avg. Node IO Delay 11
- Max. Node IO delay 38

Disk writing load is around 4 Mbytes/sec average, with peaks up to 20 Mbytes/sec.

Anyone with experience in getting better Proxmox+CEPH performance?

Thank you all in advance for taking the time to read,

Ruben.

Comment: Did you check disk usage? HDDs could easily be the bottleneck here.

Comment: Do you mean space disk used or heavy writing operations?

Disk space never went more than 85% (I manually adjusted parameters several times to rebalance and keep it under 75%)

Writing is heavy sometimes, but it is not supposed to have a huge impact in the overall performance to this levels...

Now trying a new cluster with full 2x10 Gbps ethernet connections for CEPH backnetwork, getting more than 120 Mbytes/sec writing, but as it is still a test cluster, there is no concurrent writing going on.

Comment: No I mean the disk saturation, what does `iostat -xmt /dev/sd* 1` show in the percentage column? There have been plenty of discussions around ceph and disk performance, check out the ceph-users mailing list archive what to expect of ceph.

Comment: 14/09/22 08:46:55
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           2,63    0,00    2,57    4,76    0,00   90,05

Comment: Except the IOWait value that is high, disk does not look saturated.

Comment: I'll check out in the ceph-users mailing list. Thank you for taking the time to answer.

Comment: IOWait of 90% in average is very high! Can you share the output of `iostat -xmt /dev/sd* 1` for 10 seconds or so? The last column `%util` is of interest here. If those values are close to 100% your disks are the bottleneck.

Comment: https://filebin.net/yqzk59b2tbt7ds2g

too big to add as comment...

Comment: I can't open the link.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:

- As already mentioned, make sure you create all the OSD for HDD with the DB/WALL on NVMe. This is crucial. So, not the data, but just the db !. You'll find sizing recommendations in the documentation or reserve 5-10% of data size as db size on your NVMe (for each OSD).
- Make sure you have network latency as low as possible. Anything below 200µs with you use `ping -s 1000`. For this, you might have to enable the 'cut-trough' in your switches, or think about mesh networking + FRR. For full-mesh, you might have to reduce the number of nodes to 5 if you can dedicate 4 network ports to your backend network. I recently documented a setup (french) : https://www.pivert.org/comment-ajouter-un-storage-network-a-ceph-sur-proxmox/
- If possible, replace your HDD with SSD, even with SATA, still keeping the db on NVMe.
- 10 or 25Gb network will help, but always keep the latency in mind. You might have a bit less latency with Fiber or DAC than with copper. (20-50µs)
- Do not use bluestore_cache_autotune, it's not intended to work on HCI, but as mentioned, give RAM to your OSDs, 8GB is a good start.
- I would not recommend using cache-tiering. I'm currently in troubles with it since it's not well maintained/documented. I used it for testing for a year or so, it worked well in my case, but it's not magic, and I might loose data when removing the cache-tiering pool (so currently running backups). But that's another story. Anyway, here's the doc, just interesting since you have example on how to create osd on LVM with the db on nvme: https://www.pivert.org/extend-a-ceph-cluster-with-slower-hdd-disks-with-ssd-cache-tiering/

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Got some Ceph pointers that you could follow...

- get some good NVMEs (one or two per server but if you have 8HDDs per server 1 should be enough) and put those as DB/WALL (make sure they have power protection)
- the `ceph tell osd.* bench` is not that relevant for real world, I suggest to try some FIO tests see [here](https://croit.io/blog/ceph-performance-test-and-optimization)
- set OSD `osd_memory_target` to at 8G or RAM minimum.
- in order to save some write on your HDD (data is not replicated X times) create your `RBD pool as EC` (erasure coded pool) but please do some research on that because there are some tradeoffs. Recovery takes some extra CPU calculations

All and all, hype-converged clusters are good for training, small projects and medium projects with not such a big workload on them... Keep in mind that planning is gold

Just my 2 cents,
B.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I already tried with NVMe, but size is a problem and even with them could not be more than 4 OSDs per NVMe (except some very expensive ones, outside of our budget...)

I have been investigating EC, still but not sure its better than replication (at least in our environment).

Comment: osd_memory_target is now set to 4 Gb and bluestore_cache_autotune = true, what makes kind of useless to set it higher (as far as I could investigate).

I'll try the test you mentioned and try to get some figures from them to keep advancing in the tunning.

Comment: Don't know much about tcmalloc but i think you can check the heap ram usage with the following: https://docs.ceph.com/en/quincy/rados/troubleshooting/memory-profiling/